# Execute stored procedure from cmd.exe?

Tags: sql-server-2005, cmd

Is there anyway to run a stored proc from cmd.exe ?

p.s.
I know how to create exec file c# and to run it.

I'm asking without any code :

Just me and cmd.exe.

### edit

me and cmd.exe : meaning I don't want to write any code. Internal SQL Server help exe files of sql is fine !

sorry for not clarifying this !

Comment: So no vbscript either then?  using a created helloWorld.vbs and wscript.exe on windows systems you can connect and do actions with values from a database.  [powershell](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3686521/Microsoft-Windows-Power-Shell-and-SQL-Server-2005-SMO-150-Part-4.htm) can also do it bit it's not purely cmd.exe.

Comment: Well, is this not just a matter of running some exe that connects to the database and performs some database action that then fires a trigger that then runs the SP?

Comment: I see your edit, Royi -- could you tell us your purpose? Is it to import data? Export data? Simply update something in the database? Trigger a job to run? Run an SSIS package?

Comment: @Nonym eg : windows service that runs a sp.

Comment: Then perhaps you will have to check that if that service provides command line support. Winzip, for example, provides command line support -- see if the service in question provides it. Then its documentation will give you most (if not all) of what you need..

Comment: @Nonym I think it does but without console interaction. it will just run the process in mem.

Comment: If, ultimately, it supports command line arguments -- you can write a batch file or run it from the command prompt, like: (running from command prompt cmd.exe) `app.exe arg1 value1, arg2 value2` -- Again, you'll best find out how to do it by checking that application's/services's documentation on command line support..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the [SQLCMD Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) :

An example:

`sqlcmd -E -S server_name -d database_name -Q "EXEC schema.storedprocedure parameter01, parameter02"`

If you'd like to explore other options I'd like to share this link:

[Command Prompt Utilities: Applicable for SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162816%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 not purely cmd.exe but as close as the OP is going to get without righting code.

Comment: @nonym Is there any way of using BCP instead ? whats the difference ? thanks

Comment: @xQbert By "pure" cmd.exe you mean something built into the operating system to execute a SP?

Comment: @magnus Yes.   I interpreted the OP as having just a CMD.exe (Like from DOS days and himself. (edit came after my posts) I can't see a way to do it without a utility written by either the OP or something embeded in the MSFT product lines.  (like SQLCMD) I gave a +1 to answer as it as close as I believe the OP is going to get.

Comment: Result: Must declare the scalar variable "@BusinessDate"

Answer (score 1):

- For sql server 2005+ use its **SQLCMD** utility, as @Nonim answered
- for versions prior to 2005 use its **OSQL** utility, its usage is similar to **SQLCMD**

Wrap it into the .cmd file and you're in! No needs to write something, just click'n'go! 8-)

Comment: what about BCP  , is it possible too ?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it is not intended to use for running stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

C# files are not executable. But the compiled program from them is.

CMD is not C# parser neither SQL client. From the CMD you call a program that serves a file. You and CMD can navigate to drive A: to execute file there, to delete files and so on.
CMD is emulated environment of DOS, which is also OS - you need a program to execute the SQL queries. See this (Sqlcmd program of SQL Server):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx