# schedule job for SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

How do you schedule a job in SQL Server 2016?  I've done this in 2005 but going through the tree in SSMS I don't see anything that resembles any type of scheduling that I am familiar with.

Searching finds me nothing for 2016.  In older versions I see references to Jobs and Agent but I do not see any of those choices.  Could I not have permission?  Do they have new names?  I also can't find the activity monitor which I found to be very useful (especially for terminating my processes during debugging sessions).

Comment: Are you sysadmin on the server that you're logging into?

Comment: Which **edition** of SQL Server 2016 do you have?  The SQL Server Agent which is needed to run jobs is e.g. not contained in the **Express** editions ..

Comment: @Joe,I doubt it.  But your question makes me I suspect that I must be.  Maybe I can pass this task off on my boss. :)

Comment: @marc Standard.

Comment: If you don't have a SQL Agent node and you have standard edition then you don't have sufficient security to see SQL Agent.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I went through a similar situation and had to find a workaround.

It is actually quite simple. Just have a batch file created to run msserver from shell, then schedule to run that on OS.

Assuming you're running on Windows, use Task Scheduler to run a file that goes:

```
sqlcmd -S servename -d database_name -Q "Query or procedure here"
```

I don't know if the nature of the job and the permissions you have would make this not feasable, but nevertheless, maybe it will be of help.

Comment: To be fair, got inspiration here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688426/execute-stored-procedure-from-cmd-exe/8688446#8688446 and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017